# How to transform vertical legend to the horizontal one?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

How can I transform this vertical legend to the horizontal one?

```
var legendDiv = d3.select("#legend");

var legendRow = legendDiv.selectAll("test")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("div")
    .style("margin-bottom", "2px");

legendRow.append("div")
    .html("&nbsp")
    .attr("class", "rect")
    .style("background-color", (d, i) => z(i));

legendRow.append("div")
    .html(d=>d);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the one who wrote this code you copy/pasted (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42381613/5768908). Unfortunately, you forgot to paste the CSS as well (which is important to style the `<divs>`), making the code hard to understand to other people trying to provide an answer.

If you want to show them side by side, this is an alternative:

```js
var data = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];

var z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

var legendDiv = d3.select("#legend");

var legendRow = legendDiv.selectAll("foo")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("div")

var legendRect = legendRow.append("div")
    .html("&nbsp")
    .attr("class", "rect")
    .style("background-color", (d, i) => z(i));

var legendText = legendRow.append("div")
    .attr("class", "text")
    .html(d => d);
```

```css
.rect {
  min-width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.text {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div id="legend"></div>
```